# Can you take the (Euclidean) norm of a scalar quantity (non-vector)?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces

Context: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701869/differentiate-determinant-function-on-matrix)

My question is whether or not you can take the (Euclidean) norm of a scalar non-vector quantity. My intuition is no, but I just wanted to confirm it.

I understand that a norm in essence gives you a 'length' or 'magnitude' which is a scalar quantity, so if you already had a scalar quantity $k$, does $\Vert k \Vert = k$ where $\Vert . \Vert$ is a norm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\Bbb R$ is related to the absolute value $|\cdot|$ via the silly computation $\|x\| = \|x1\| = |x|\|1\| = \|1\||x|$, since you can regard the "vector" $x$ as the number it actually is. Corollary: the only norm $\|\cdot\|$ in the vector space $\Bbb R$ with $\|1\| = 1$ is $\|\cdot\| = |\cdot|$.

Comment: Hi, I'm still a little confused. Are you saying that, on $\mathbb{R}$, every norm is essentially equivalent to the absolute value? So, if you had some linear combination in $\mathbb{R}$, the norm of this would be the absolute value of the linear combination?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$